# Join two lists with one to many relationship

Tags: c#

I have two classes like so.  One has a list of the other class and are linked by key1.

```
public class Alpha
{
    public key1 { get; set; }
    public List<Bravo> { //getter and setter }
}

public class Bravo
{
    public key1 { get; set; }
    public someProp { get; set; }
}
```

I have a method that gets two lists of Alpha and Bravo and I need to join them into one list of Alpha.  Each Alpha has a one to many relationship with Bravo but now I have many Alpha.  I know I could iterate through both lists but is there a faster way?

```
public List<Alpha> Join (List<Alpha> alphaList, List<Bravo> bravoList)
{
    //match each Bravo with it's corresponding Alpha
}
```

Example:

```
alphaList = { 
    item1 { key1 = 1, bravoList { } }
    item2 { key1 = 2, bravoList { } }
    item3 { key1 = 3, bravoList { } }
}

bravoList = {
    itemA { key1 = 1, someProp }
    itemB { key1 = 2, someProp }
    itemC { key1 = 2, someProp }
    itemD { key1 = 3, someProp }
    itemE { key1 = 3, someProp }
}

finalList = {
    item1 { key1 = 1, bravoList { itemA } }
    item2 { key1 = 2, bravoList { itemB, itemC } }
    item3 { key1 = 3, bravoList { itemD, itemE } }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, you aren't clear. Can you provide some examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class Helper
{
    public List<Alpha> Join(List<Alpha> alphaList, List<Bravo> bravoList)
    {
        return alphaList.Select(a => new Alpha() { key1 = a.key1, list = bravoList.Where(b => b.key1 == a.key1).ToList() }).ToList();
    }
}

public class Alpha
{
    public int key1 { get; set; }

    public List<Bravo> list { get; set; }
}

public class Bravo
{
    public int key1 { get; set; }

    public string someProp { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: what is "list" in "list = bravoList.Where..."?

Comment: This is your property "public List<Bravo> { //getter and setter }"

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Enumerable.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344797.aspx):

```
public List<Alpha> Join(List<Alpha> alphaList, List<Bravo> bravoList)
{
    return alphaList.Join(bravoList, a => a.key1, b => b.key1, (a,b) => a)
                    .ToList();
}
```

This will return a list of all `Alphas` which `key1` is also in the list of `Bravos`.

**Update**:

```
public List<Alpha> Join(List<Alpha> alphaList, List<Bravo> bravoList)
{
    List<Alpha> finalList = alphaList
        .Select(a => new Alpha { 
             key1 = a.key1, 
             bravoList =  bravoList.Where(b => b.key1 == a.key1).ToList()
         }).ToList();
    return finalList;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your comments, the list of `Bravo`'s on `Alpha` is pretty much extraneous since it's not being managed in any way by an ORM.

If you want to join, here's the simplest way to use it:

```
public IEnumerable<Tuple<Alpha, Bravo>> Join (IEnumerable<Alpha> alphaList, IEnumerable<Bravo> bravoList)
{
    return (from a in alphaList
            join b in bravoList on a.key1 equals b.key1
            select Tuple.Create(a, b))
           .ToList();
}
```

Since this is a many-to-one relationship, this will probably be more useful:

```
public Lookup<Alpha, Bravo> Join (IEnumerable<Alpha> alphaList, IEnumerable<Bravo> bravoList)
{
    return (from a in alphaList 
            join b in bravoList on a.key1 equal b.key1 into g
            select new { a, g })
           .ToLookup(x => x.a, x.g)
}
```

Notice the `into` clause; it allows you to grouped the joined items together. I then turn the groupings into a [`Lookup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx) for easy access.

If you *do* want to keep the list on `Alpha`, there's probably no way to do this without either a `foreach`-loop or an awful lot of work building your own mini-ORM.

Comment: So the Bravo list in the Alpha object is empty. I get a list of Bravo from a database and need to join them into the Alpha list.

Comment: @user1608132 are you using an ORM for this, e.g. entity framework, nhibernate, etc.?

Comment: @user1608132 I strongly recommend you look into incorporating a full ORM into your project. It massively simplifies this kind of task. See my updated answer for another solution.